# Assimp Sample starting error

Tags: opengl, assimp

I installed the Assimp library on windows, and liked the files then just copy-pasted the SimpleOpenGL sample and deleted the struct words(most of them) In order to clear the errors I was getting.

Now, I do not have any errors but the program tells me this whenever I try to run it:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002).Click OK to close the application.
```

Any ideeas for a fix for this ( I have all the dlls from assimp in the project folder. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use renamed Assimp32.dll to Assimp32d.dll

Comment: This worked for me. Can you please explain why this happens? Would really appreciate that.